# gdb search regex up

Tags: search, gdb, debugging, gnu

I'm debugging my program with gdb and I have found a weird value for a variable x0.

the `search x0 =` will only show me the line in the current frame where the "x0 = " regex is written from the last listed line in the frame, on. Is there a possibility to find the regex in an **upward**  direction? Like, if x0 has a weird value, I would like the gdb to search for the "x0 = " regex from the current line, up. This is much easier than just listing above, and above, and above...

Thanks

Comment: what  `search` command does? Is it searching in sources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Search.html#index-search-450

**reverse-search** *regexp*

> The command `reverse-search regexp' checks each line, starting with the one before the last line listed and going backward, for a match for regexp. It lists the line that is found. You can abbreviate this command as rev.

And the `search` command is just an alias of `forward-search` command.

Comment: tomislav-maric, So, you can press "v" symbol just left to the my answer to close the question.